# Creating a status update from google hangouts through php

Tags: php, api, google-hangouts

So I am trying to figure out if I can create a simple custom PHP script that takes data from a google hangout link and displays back if it is in session.

I am pretty new to Google APi's. My end goal is to create a button on a website that appears whenever someone has joined into a certain designated HANGOUT link.

Do you think this is possible? Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Here was I was thinking:

```
$stuff = strip_tags(file_get_contents("https://hangouts.google.com/hangouts/_/4im2yhs5kry4vjhlu4yop25tsea"));

$eStrings = explode(' ', $stuff);
```

I would then retrieve the data from the code and see if it is live or not. If at top of the screen it reads: "You are the only one here" then it is automatically assumed that the session has not begun.

Problem=> You get directed to the google login screen because you need user access.

If anyone has ideas please advise.

Comment: this might help you: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is a [PHP API SDK for Google](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/) in beta, it doesn't appear to support Hangouts at all. Google does however expose a client-side JavaScript interface for Hangouts that you should be able to emit and use from your PHP server-side code.

Using the JS interface, you could use the [gapi.hangout.onParticipantsChanged](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.html#gapi.hangout.onParticipantsChanged) event notification for a given Hangout to know when someone has joined.

Then leverage the [gapi.hangouts.getParticipants()](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.html#gapi.hangout.getParticipants) function to pull a list of who's in the hangout and determine if your button should show for the current user.